# Multiple filters in ECT External Item Picker in SharePoint 2010 BCS?

Tags: bcs, filter

I am using SharePoint 2010 BCS to connect to a SQL Server database table and created an External Content Type (ECT).
In this ECT you can specify a filter and I have done that, and I mapped the ECT to some external columns in a SharePoint document library.
When I add or edit an library item, I can select which ECT row to use using an "External Item Picker" to view the filtered list of data items from my SQL Server table.
I am trying to determine (without any luck) if I can somehow get multiple filter items to show in the External Item Picker's filter drop down list.
I can't see to figure out how to do that.

I would like to have a handful of filters (e.g. by year, 2010, 2009, 2008, etc), but when I am designing the filter in SPD, it only seem to let me make one filter per ECT.
Do I need to create multiple ReadList methods to create multiple filters? and if so, will all those filters show up as options in the same external item picker?

I am experimenting on my own, but wondered if anyone has already been down this path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You need to create them on the External Content type, through SharePoint Designer. Edit your Read List method - and when you configure your Filters Parameters add the filters you need. You should be able to add many filters.

When configuring the filters, make sure you check the "Use to create match list in external item picker".

You should then get several filters in the external data picker.